# SQL - Indented Multi Level Number List

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to build a query based on a Parent/Child Hierarchal table. IE, I have a parentID and that has a childID. However, that ChildID may also be a parent and down the tree we go.
The goal though is to get a column output that represents the structure as numbers. For example:

1

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.1.3

1.2

I have sample table structure here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75426f/1)

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_test](
    [ParentItemSpecID] [int] NULL,
    [ChildItemSpecID] [int] NULL,
    [TotalQtyPerRoot] [float] NULL,
    [level] [float] NULL,
    [TreeSort] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (1, 2, 1, 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (2, 3, 1, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 4, 1, 3, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (4, 5, 1, 4, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (5, 6, 1, 5, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 7, 1, 6, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 8, 1, 6, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 9, 2, 6, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 10, 1, 6, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 11, 1, 6, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (6, 12, 1, 6, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (5, 13, 1, 5, 11)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (4, 14, 1, 4, 12)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 15, 1, 3, 13)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 16, 2, 3, 14)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 17, 1, 3, 15)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 18, 7, 3, 16)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 19, 2, 3, 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 20, 2, 3, 18)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 21, 2, 3, 19)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 22, 1, 3, 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 23, 1, 3, 21)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 24, 24, 3, 22)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 25, 24, 3, 23)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 26, 24, 3, 24)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 27, 2, 3, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 28, 4, 4, 26)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 29, 2, 4, 27)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 30, 4, 4, 28)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 31, 2, 4, 29)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 32, 2, 4, 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 33, 2, 4, 31)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 34, 2, 4, 32)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 35, 2, 4, 33)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 36, 4, 4, 34)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 37, 2, 4, 35)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (27, 38, 0.04, 4, 36)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 39, 4, 3, 37)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 40, 1, 3, 38)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 41, 1, 3, 39)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 42, 1, 3, 40)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 43, 2, 3, 41)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (3, 44, 1, 3, 42)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (44, 45, 1, 4, 43)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_test] ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES (45, 46, 1, 5, 44)
GO
```

If you refer to Parent ID 3, ChildID 27. At that point, the numbering should look like 1.1.14 and then start to go to 1.1.14.1, 1.1.14.2, 1.1.14.3

I have attempted numerous rank, row_number(), Dense_rank...I just can't get it that each time it steps to a new level (level +1), it has to take the previous rows value and start from there counting again.
Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to avoid using a loop or cursor.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off using a [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Significant Digits seems like a good idea, but they tend to have a very short shelf-life.  It will not be long before re-sequencing becomes an issue.  An ID, Parent and Presentation Sequence structure will serve you better and is far more sustainable.    I should note that the Presentation Sequence is limited to siblings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) (`rcte`) to get the numbering (`Number`) you want. I also included the hierarchical path (`PathWithIds`) as a bonus.

Your data is a bit unusual as there is no line with `ChildItemSpecID=1, ParentItemSpecID=null` as root element. Normally the root in the recursive CTE would be defined as "the element with no parent" (`ParentItemSpecID=null`). This solution has a more hard-coded approach with some alternatives listed.

I left out the the `TotalQtyPerRoot`, `level` and `TreeSort` columns in the result. It is not clear to me if these columns are part of your data or output from your attempts. You can add them or even calculate them as part of the recursive CTE if you want.

**Sample data**

```
declare @_test table
(
    [ParentItemSpecID] [int] NULL,
    [ChildItemSpecID] [int] NULL,
    [TotalQtyPerRoot] [float] NULL,
    [level] [float] NULL,
    [TreeSort] [int] NULL
);

INSERT @_test ([ParentItemSpecID], [ChildItemSpecID], [TotalQtyPerRoot], [level], [TreeSort]) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
(3, 4, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 5, 1, 4, 3),
(5, 6, 1, 5, 4),
(6, 7, 1, 6, 5),
(6, 8, 1, 6, 6),
(6, 9, 2, 6, 7),
(6, 10, 1, 6, 8),
(6, 11, 1, 6, 9),
(6, 12, 1, 6, 10),
(5, 13, 1, 5, 11),
(4, 14, 1, 4, 12),
(3, 15, 1, 3, 13),
(3, 16, 2, 3, 14),
(3, 17, 1, 3, 15),
(3, 18, 7, 3, 16),
(3, 19, 2, 3, 17),
(3, 20, 2, 3, 18),
(3, 21, 2, 3, 19),
(3, 22, 1, 3, 20),
(3, 23, 1, 3, 21),
(3, 24, 24, 3, 22),
(3, 25, 24, 3, 23),
(3, 26, 24, 3, 24),
(3, 27, 2, 3, 25),
(27, 28, 4, 4, 26),
(27, 29, 2, 4, 27),
(27, 30, 4, 4, 28),
(27, 31, 2, 4, 29),
(27, 32, 2, 4, 30),
(27, 33, 2, 4, 31),
(27, 34, 2, 4, 32),
(27, 35, 2, 4, 33),
(27, 36, 4, 4, 34),
(27, 37, 2, 4, 35),
(27, 38, 0.04, 4, 36),
(3, 39, 4, 3, 37),
(3, 40, 1, 3, 38),
(3, 41, 1, 3, 39),
(3, 42, 1, 3, 40),
(3, 43, 2, 3, 41),
(3, 44, 1, 3, 42),
(44, 45, 1, 4, 43),
(45, 46, 1, 5, 44);
```

**Solution**

```
with rcte as
(
    select  t1.ChildItemSpecID,
            t1.ParentItemSpecID,
            convert(nvarchar, convert(nvarchar, t1.ParentItemSpecID) + '/' + convert(nvarchar, t1.ChildItemSpecID)) as 'PathWithIds',
            convert(nvarchar, 1) as 'Number'
    from @_test t1
    where t1.ParentItemSpecID = 1   -- select root element (option 1)
       -- t1.ChildItemSpecID = 2    -- select root element (option 2)
       -- t1.level = 1              -- select root element (option 3)
       union all
    select  t2.ChildItemSpecID,
            t2.ParentItemSpecID,
            convert(nvarchar, t1.PathWithIds + '/' + convert(nvarchar, t2.ChildItemSpecID)), -- extend number starting from parent number
            convert(nvarchar, t1.Number + '.' + convert(nvarchar, row_number() over(order by t2.ChildItemSpecID)))
    from @_test t2
    join rcte t1
        on t1.ChildItemSpecID = t2.ParentItemSpecID
)
select rcte.ChildItemSpecID, rcte.ParentItemSpecID, rcte.PathWithIds, rcte.Number
from rcte
order by rcte.Number;
```

**Result**

```
ChildItemSpecID ParentItemSpecID PathWithIds      Number
--------------- ---------------- ---------------- -------------
2               1                1/2              1
3               2                1/2/3            1.1
4               3                1/2/3/4          1.1.1
5               4                1/2/3/4/5        1.1.1.1
6               5                1/2/3/4/5/6      1.1.1.1.1
7               6                1/2/3/4/5/6/7    1.1.1.1.1.1
8               6                1/2/3/4/5/6/8    1.1.1.1.1.2
9               6                1/2/3/4/5/6/9    1.1.1.1.1.3
10              6                1/2/3/4/5/6/10   1.1.1.1.1.4
11              6                1/2/3/4/5/6/11   1.1.1.1.1.5
12              6                1/2/3/4/5/6/12   1.1.1.1.1.6
13              5                1/2/3/4/5/13     1.1.1.1.2
14              4                1/2/3/4/14       1.1.1.2
23              3                1/2/3/23         1.1.10
24              3                1/2/3/24         1.1.11
25              3                1/2/3/25         1.1.12
26              3                1/2/3/26         1.1.13
27              3                1/2/3/27         1.1.14
28              27               1/2/3/27/28      1.1.14.1
37              27               1/2/3/27/37      1.1.14.10
38              27               1/2/3/27/38      1.1.14.11
29              27               1/2/3/27/29      1.1.14.2
30              27               1/2/3/27/30      1.1.14.3
31              27               1/2/3/27/31      1.1.14.4
32              27               1/2/3/27/32      1.1.14.5
33              27               1/2/3/27/33      1.1.14.6
34              27               1/2/3/27/34      1.1.14.7
35              27               1/2/3/27/35      1.1.14.8
36              27               1/2/3/27/36      1.1.14.9
39              3                1/2/3/39         1.1.15
40              3                1/2/3/40         1.1.16
41              3                1/2/3/41         1.1.17
42              3                1/2/3/42         1.1.18
43              3                1/2/3/43         1.1.19
15              3                1/2/3/15         1.1.2
44              3                1/2/3/44         1.1.20
45              44               1/2/3/44/45      1.1.20.1
46              45               1/2/3/44/45/46   1.1.20.1.1
16              3                1/2/3/16         1.1.3
17              3                1/2/3/17         1.1.4
18              3                1/2/3/18         1.1.5
19              3                1/2/3/19         1.1.6
20              3                1/2/3/20         1.1.7
21              3                1/2/3/21         1.1.8
22              3                1/2/3/22         1.1.9
```